# Show that if $n>1$, every continuous map $f:\mathbb{S}^n\to \mathbb{S}^1$ is nulhomotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

**Show that if $n>1$, every continuous map $f:\mathbb{S}^n\to \mathbb{S}^1$ is nulhomotopic, and show that every continuous map $f: P^2\to \mathbb{S}^1$ is nulhomotopic.**

I have already demonstrated the following result and I would like to know if I can use that here:

[image]

I know that $\pi_1(X)$ is finite if $X=\mathbb{S}^n$ or $X=P^2$, I also know that $\mathbb{S}^n$ is arc-connected, but are the other things in the hypothesis fulfilled in order to apply this result?

Comment: Notice that $S^n$ and $P^2$ are (topological) manifolds. Since they are homeomorphic to an euclidean space locally, they are locally path-connected. Of course $P^2$ ($\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{C}P^2$) is path-connected. The most difficult part, in my opinion, is that $\pi_1(X)$ is finite, but you already knew it.

Answer (score 2):

First, $\mathbb S^n$ is locally path connected, for any neighborhood of a point of $\mathbb S^n$ contains an $\varepsilon$-ball of the point, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Second, $P^2$ is path connected,  for it is the image of $\mathbb S^2$ under a continuous (quotient) map.

Third, $P^2$ is locally path connected.   This is because any neighborhood of a point contains a neighborhood on which the preimage of the aforementioned quotient map is homeomorphic to two copies of $\mathbb R^2$, hence is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.